# Account lock issue in LDAP authentication C#

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, ldap, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented Active Directory authentication in my application and it is working properly.

But when entering an incorrect password five times, the account gets locked.

Is there any possible way to avoid account locking for the invalid authentication?

Thank u,
Ganesh. K

Comment: That's an Active Directory policy - if the AD domain admin has set the rule to be that an account is locked after five unsuccessful login attempts, then *you* cannot override this in your application ....

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't have control over that because this is an Active Directory password policy settings.

Answer (score 0):

[Active Directory Account Lockout](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Account%20Lockout) is controlled by the the Domain Policy, a Group Policy Object (GPO) linked to the domain.

You can change the policy.

[Lockouttime](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Lockouttime) can only triggered by the system itself.

You may also un-lock an account by setting the Lockouttime attribute to "0".